# The widget displaying over htmlelementview is not detecting gestures in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I have placed a dropdown button in appbar which shows a dropdown list. In the body of my page, i am displaying a iframewidget using htmlelementview . When i click the dropdown button,the dropdown list is displaying over the iframe widget(which is the body of the page) and if i select the option from my dropdown list,there is no gesture detection(because it is displaying over the iframe) .
How to solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69386468/flutter-on-tap-not-working-on-html-element-view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the dropdown list in a `PointerInterceptor` from pub.dev: [pointer_interceptor](https://pub.dev/packages/pointer_interceptor)

Comment: @EAvijay did you wrap the list itself or just the dropdown button

Comment: @Irsvmb this helps.but the widget is rebuilding for every click.

Comment: I wrapped the child of the DropdownMenuItem with a PointerInterceptor. But this throws the following error for every item in the DropdownMenuItem list. Did you experience the same or were you able to fix it?


    Error: setState() called after dispose(): _PlatformViewLinkState#568ff(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)