# Flutter on tap not working on Html element view

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

The webpage I'm loading contains a [HtmlElementView class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/HtmlElementView-class.html) which will load an URL. And I am having an action in app bar and when I am tapping on a option, It is not responding.
[image: Reference image]
In the reference image the account settings option is clickable because it is outside the HtmlElementView   but the others two options are not clickable because it is on top of the HtmlElementView.  Help me with an solution for this.

Comment: FWIW HtmlElementView will consume all events even when other Flutter UI elements are on top of them even with PointerIgnore() and the like. Here's a package to help route the inputs: https://pub.dev/packages/pointer_interceptor

Comment: That's literally what the readme says it addresses: "When overlaying Flutter widgets on top of HtmlElementView widgets that respond to mouse gestures (handle clicks, for example), the clicks will be consumed by the HtmlElementView, and not relayed to Flutter"

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no in easy way of dealing with this in flutter.
So the best option is to use [pub.dev/packages/pointer_interceptor](https://pub.dev/packages/pointer_interceptor)

Thanks to @Pat9RB for finding this!